# Android sqlit update fail

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have got the follwoing hex String of the photo captured as follow

```
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
```

and I am going to update this to the sqlite database of the Android tablet

```
boolean success = soDbHelper.updateAddressPhoto(orderid, fileHex);
                    Log.d("ADDRESS" , String.valueOf(success));


   public boolean updateAddressPhoto(String refno, String sign) {

            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_PHOTO_ADDRESS_HEX, sign);

            return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_REFNO + "=" + refno, null) > 0;
        }
```

It does not show any exceptions but it shows false , means no rows affected

Does it imply the string is too long ?

Comment: Try to save a shorter String. if it works than the String is too long and you need to find an alternative. if it doesn't work you are doing something wrong with the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try with proper syntax of update query ,

like this

db.update(Table,values,COLUMN + "=?",args);

Also another suggestion is to check the type of HEX , may be it could be too longer than its column datatype.